# Issue with Anova in R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, anova

[This is a picture of my column names in a value and then the anova that I have set up for it that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iykh8.png)

I want to make a be able to switch out each column name in my anova in a loop so I don't have to rewrite the code and just change the column name.

Tried setting up a for loop and couldn't get it to work.

```
for (i in col_values) {
 one.way <- aov(i ~ Treatment, treatment_data)
}
```

Thought I'd ask here. Not particularly needing to stick with for loops, so open to any and all suggestions. Thanks for any suggestions you may have!

Comment: Can you provide a small example of  input data using `dput()` or a built in data set, so that we can run your example?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in a formula call:

```r
for (i in col_values) {
 one.way <- aov(as.formula(paste(i, " ~ Treatment")), treatment_data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

y <- names(mtcars)[1:3] %>% 
  set_names()

map(y, ~aov(reformulate(.x, "qsec"), data = mtcars))
#> $mpg
#> Call:
#>    aov(formula = reformulate(.x, "qsec"), data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Terms:
#>                      mpg Residuals
#> Sum of Squares  17.35226  81.63589
#> Deg. of Freedom        1        30
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.649605
#> Estimated effects may be unbalanced
#> 
#> $cyl
#> Call:
#>    aov(formula = reformulate(.x, "qsec"), data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Terms:
#>                      cyl Residuals
#> Sum of Squares  34.60301  64.38514
#> Deg. of Freedom        1        30
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.464982
#> Estimated effects may be unbalanced
#> 
#> $disp
#> Call:
#>    aov(formula = reformulate(.x, "qsec"), data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Terms:
#>                     disp Residuals
#> Sum of Squares  18.61906  80.36909
#> Deg. of Freedom        1        30
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.636756
#> Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>